# Elm 0.18 how to replace Html.App

Tags: elm

I am new to elm and I'm working on the ElmBridge tutorial. I understand Html.App collapsed into Html and any Html.App imports need to refer to Html.program instead. I replaced Html.App with Html.program but the module is not importing.

When I run elm-make I get a syntax problem saying it's looking for an upper case name? Screen shot of my Main.elm and error below.

Main.elm

[image]

Error message

[image]

Comment: Did you you know that you can copy/paste your code here and click on the "code sample" button to make your question more readable? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't import `Html.program`, only `Html`.

```
import Html
```

Then you use it by referencing as you already have,

```
main = Html.program {...}
-- or...
main = Html.beginnerProgram {...}
```

Comment: @Dori Then you can mark his answer as the good one. It will be helpful for others ;)

Comment: You can specifically ` import Html exposing (program) ` if that's all you need

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Program" module. It's in Html itself.
Just do `import Html` and then you can use `Html.program`